# Meteor Cordova Build: Build my Cordova app but cannot run on device or simulator

Tags: cordova, meteor, io

I have built a Cordova app with Meteor before and I have never run into this issue.

See this:

[image]

As you can see I can only select My Mac as the simulator.

Here is my build command

`../app-build --directory --server https://app.com --mobile-settings settings.json`

What is going on. How can I get my app to run?

Answer (score 0):

Does it work on `meteor run ios`?

Make sure there are no errors on the browser before running. You can also use `meteor run --debug`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Now its working. Here is what the issue was in mobile-settings.js

It was the 'name' key in the App.info section.

I had changed the name since the first time I ran the simulator.

If you change the name and then build it breaks the app.

If you comment out the App.info section it will work.

But to get it to work with the new name.

Do this

1) `meteor remove-platform ios`
2) `meteor add-platform ios`
3) Then build your project again with the right app name in the mobile-settings.js file.

Then it should work.

A related link: https://forums.meteor.com/t/mobile-mobile-config-name-breaks-project/8710/18